# Getting error of <template #innerView> while updating from angular 2 to angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-template, updating, let

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw4A1.png)

> I got error as 'Template parse errors: "let-" is only supported on
>   ng-template elements' when updating from angular 2 to angular 4. I
>   have attached the screenshot for the same.

Comment: add some code to help you

Comment: it should be `<ng-template #innerView>`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2, you were allowed to use the `<template>` tag for `TemplateRef`s, but since this is an actual HTML tag, it was deprecated in favor of `<ng-template>` in Angular 4. So just change the name of the tag and it should work.

Comment: but in my project i have not used <template>.

Comment: I have used templateUrl.

Comment: @KushalPatel, no I mean in your HTML file, replace <template></template> with <ng-template></ng-template>

Comment: but i have not used <template></template> in any html file.

Comment: Maybe one of your dependencies.